# What does the 2 stand for in "iPhone (2)" in find my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, applications

Under the 'Find my iPhone' app, one of our phones listed now has a 2 beside it:
iPhone (2)
Listed like the above. What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means you have two devices using the same name. It has to do something to try separate them, so it adds a (2).

This can also happen if a single device is restored or set up as a new device, but is actually the same one. The initial device is preserved but a new one is set up to attempt to differentiate.

To fix this - go to the device and set a new name in the settings app. When it next connects to iCloud the name in Find My will update to reflect the current name for that device.